# Alignment in HTML TD and Div inside it

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have `TD` tag `align = "right"`

and one `div` inside it with `align="left"` Basically what i want to achieve is

- `Align TD` contents to `right`. (in this case DIV)
- But align all `content`s inside `div` to `left`

but that is not happening here all contents inside div are aligning to right as specified in TD tag.

Any body have any idea why??

Thank you in advance

Regards,
Mona

Answer (score 1):

```
<td align="right">
    <div style="text-align:left;"></div>
</td>
```

Or using CSS:

```
td[align=right] > div{
   text-align:left;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/odaZUkEz/1/edit)**